# how to transform simtime to double value in omnet++?

Tags: c++, omnet++

I have simtime_t value which is include duration value.
I want to translate simtime_t value to double so that I can figure how much byte I send during that simtime_t.

Thank you for your regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dbl()`, for example:

```
simtime_t t1;
// ...
double t2 = t1.dbl();
```

Comment: what about doing the opposite?  from double to simtime_t

Comment: `simtime_t` has overloaded assignment operator, so one can just write: `double a = 12.71; simtime_t t = a;`.

Comment: does this overloaded assignment operator check if the double value is bigger than the max size of the simtime_t type?

Comment: Strictly speaking: `operator=(double x)` raises an error when `fabs(i64) > INT64_MAX_DBL` where `INT64_MAX_DBL` is the most positive int64_t value, represented as double, equals to 9.22337203685e18.